# pip list (or pip show) shows different version of package (SQLAlchemy) in Jupyter Notebook then when I run the command in Anaconda Prompt

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pip, sqlalchemy, version-control, anaconda

So. I have been trying to get pandasql to work, I get a certain error. When researching this, I found that I needed to downgrade SQLAlchemy to 1.4.46. So I did just that. The problem is the following:

When I use `pip show SQLalchemy` (in Anaconda Prompt) I see: [Anaconda Prompt printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXasG.png)

From this prompt, I start up my jupyter notebook, then:

When I use `pip show SQLalchemy` (in Jupyter Notebook) I see: [Jupyter Notebook printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3Fbn.png)

(p.s. I use conda install mostly, but when I can't get it to work I use pip install.)

Does anyone know what causes this inconsistency? Any help appreciated.

I tried un-installing and installing sqlalchemy, restarting computer and restarting my kernel. Could not find any related problems online.

Comment: Different Pythons, different `pip`s, different `site-packages` directories…

Comment: Thanks for you reponse. Do you have any idea how I could fix this?

Comment: Run `/path/to/python -m pip` with that one Python you want to use.

Comment: And then? Would it be wise to uninstall the other one (and how)? Because I think my jupyter notebook is still starting up from the other one, although I changed the directory. Thanks for your help

Comment: "*Would it be wise to uninstall the other one …?*" No, why? "*Because I think my jupyter notebook is still starting up from the other one…*" This means you've istalled `jupyter-notebook` using the wrong python. By uninstalling it you would destroy the program. Instead install `jupyter-notebook` using the python you want and start it with your python.